# Using glGenerateMipmap() with glCopyTexImage2D()

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures, mipmaps

I wish to upload textures with non-zero mipmap levels using glCopyTexImage2D().
I am using following code for the same :

```
// Render Some Geometry

GLint mipmap_level = 1;

glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);  

glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,mipmap_level,GL_RGBA16_SNORM,0,0,128,128,0);
// Five other glCopyTexImage2D() calls to load textures

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

//Render geometry
```

Here, if I use mipmap_level = 1 the geometry is not drawn at all. How exactly does mipmap levels work in conjunction with glCopyTexImage2D() API ?
I suppose that using level = 1 , loads 64x64 texture i.e. the first sampled mipmap.
Using glGenerateMipmap() call before glCopyTexImage2D() will not make any sense. So how exactly the driver will load a non zero mipmap level using glCopyTexImage2D() ?

Answer (score 2):

You first set the image for mipmap level 1 and then you call `glGenerateMipmap` to automatically generate mipmaps from the image of the first mipmap level, **which is mipmap level 0**. So all mipmap images following level 0 just get overwritten by the automatically generated images. `glGenerateMipmap` doesn't care how you set the image for mipmap level 0, it just assumes you did. On the other hand I don't see you specifying an image for level 0, so it will probably just contain rubbish or be regarded as incomplete, which will make any use of the corresponding texture fail.

In the end I hope this question doesn't just amount to knowing that in most programming languages one usually starts to count at 0 instead of 1, and so does OpenGL.

**EDIT:** As *datenwolf* points out in his comment, you can change the base mipmap level to be used for mipmap-filtering and as input for `glGenerateMipmap` by doing a

```
glTexParamteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 1);
```

But don't do this just because you want to start counting at 1 instead of 0. If on the other hand you have a valid image for mipmap level 0 and want to set one for level 1 and use this for computing the other levels, then changing the base level to 1 before calling `glGenerateMipmap` (and probably back to 0 aftwerwards) can be a good idea, though I cannot come up with a usecase for this approach right away.

Comment: Not quite. glGenerateMipmap does generate mipmaps starting from the base level, which by default is 0, up to the max level, which by default 1000. Both values can be changed using glTexParameter on the tokens GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL

Comment: @datenwolf Hah, indeed. But since the OP didn't mention this I guess he hasn't changed the base level (or is aware of this feature). Good point, though.

Comment: The main idea behind this feature is to make deferred texture image loading possible. For example in interactive applications this can be used to load only the low resolution LOD levels of a texture (and model), and only as the viewer approaches the model, higher resolution data is uploaded. Depending on the quality of the driver, setting only a subrange of mipmap levels also allows the driver to swap out deselected levels to free up fast memory for other resources.

Comment: So setting mipmap level to 1 in glCopyTexImage2d() call, followed by a call to glGenerateMipMaps() will automatically load the non zero mipmp . Clear till this point. But in my case when I say mipmap_level = 1 , nothing is rendered. 
I am not specifying image for level 0 because I have already rendered a geometry and I am using glCopyTexImage2D() call.
Is there any other way we can specify level 0 image then use glCopyTexImage2D() call ?
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @maverick9888 From your comment I don't completely understand if you got the message: Setting the image for level 1 (however done, maybe with `glCopyTexImage2D`) and then calling `glGenerateMipmaps` will **overwrite** the image for level 1 with the one generated by `glGenerateMipmaps`, which is computed automatically from the image of level 0. But if you didn't set the image for level 0 beforehand, **this will just not work**, because then you don't have a valid image to compute the mipmaps from.

Comment: @maverick9888 If you want the rendered output to be used as texture, what if you just set the image for level 0 (instead of 1) with your call to `glCopyTexImage2D`? I don't see any use in using one image for level 0 and a totally different image for level 1 and all following.

Comment: Using level 0 works perfectly fine. I was wondering if I can use subsequent mipmap levels. But from what I understand ,unless I have level 0 defined there is no point ib using level 1 or more.
So can we make a general statement that glCopyTexImage2D() supports level 0 mipmap only ?

Comment: @maverick9888 No, `glCopyTexImage2D` (like any other `gl...Tex...Image` function) perfectly supports mipmap level 1, like any other mipmap level. It's just `glGenerateMipmap` that by default (although you can change this as written in the answer) uses level 0 to compute the images for all subsequent levels (and thus overwrites any image you may have previously set manually). You can set the image of each and every mipmap level manually using the `gl...Tex...Image` functions, `glGenerateMipmap` is just a convenience function to compute them automatically.

Comment: @maverick9888 And as written in the edit to the answer, you can configure `glGenerateMipmap` to compute the images for all levels >1 using the image of level 1. It's just that I don't see any reason to do this in contrast to either just setting image 0 and computing all subsequent levels automatically or setting all images manually without using `glGenerateMipmaps`.

Comment: @maverick9888 I hope you understand what mipmaps actually are for. They are used for texture filtering of a single texture and should thus usually all resemble the same image at decreasing resolutions (and `glGenerateMipmap` computes those images from the image at the highest resolution). They are not used to manage multiple arbitrary indidual images inside a single texture.

Comment: I totally understand that glGenerateMipmap() is used for texture filtering of a single texture.
But if glCopyTexImage2D() support levl = 1, how can this be accomplished ? Because we need to set base level i.e. level 0 using our first call to glCopyTexImage2D() . 
In case of glTexImage2D() API it is possible to call it multiple times for defining the images for various mipmap levels but how is that possible with glCopyTexImage2D().
Calling glTexParameter() with GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL ,will define what the base level is but not the data needed to initialise it.

Comment: Also using glGenerateMipmap() creates mipmap level automatically.If we consider Christian Rau example that as the camera moves closer to an object the High Resolution images will be loaded. So how does it happens in programatic terms ? Does the graphics driver is responsible for deciding which Mipmap level to upload ? Or the developer has to call glTexImage2D() repeatatively in that case?